# how can I add the .net framework installer to a deployment project?

Tags: c#, windows

I have created one windows project and created a deployment project.
When I given the .msi setup file to client & if he do not have .net installed on his machine it say to install .net first.

What I want is that if client's machine does not have .NET then setup file can starts the installing it silently otherwise it can install my application.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use the crappy deployment projects, get WIX and use WIX. It is VS integrated, and it works a lot better than deployment proejcts which dont even produce valid MSI files per validation.

Second, this is not what MSI files CAN do - no way. MSI files are control databases. Installing prereqquisites is done by the .exe file that predates the MSI file (th "bootstrapper"). Both WIIX and deployment projects can handle this. For Wix the reference is http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm. I wont touch deployment projects because they are outdated.

Comment: can u tell me how can i use bootstrapper to do this

Comment: RTFM. Really. I pointed you to an example for wix - does not get more detailed than that. YOu think I copy / paste the content here? What for?

Comment: i dont know about WIX i never used before

Comment: Your questin basically says you dont know anything about installers except "there is an msi file". THere is more to it. Like rules (that installer perojects do not follow).

Answer (score 1):

here the article you like to see : [Add Prerequisites of .NET Framework in Visual Studio Setup Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Add_framework_in_setup.aspx)

Comment: Can i have to give only .msi file of setup to user or .net framework folder also

Comment: No, you can not. As I said MSI files can not install prerequisites per definition (of the MSI standard).

Comment: Use a bootstrapper. Maybe realize that repeating the same question (like you do) gets people impatient and wont change the only valid answer you get. Deal with reality. You can not install a prerequisite legally (per MSI specs & best practices) from a MSI file.